# MS Graph API: looking for ALIAS of user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been playing with the MS graph api. Nice stuff.

One thing keeps me puzzled, i can't seem to find the ALIAS of a user, in the users properties. The people search `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people?$search="123456"` gives me the exact right result. But none of the properties matches the alias field (`employeeID`, `userprincipalname`, etc).
I know it's in there cause the full outlook client can dig it out...

Any tips (probably I'm overlooking something very trivial)

**outlook screenshot:**
[image: outlook screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

A user's "alias" is held in the `mailNickname`. By default, this property isn't returned as part of the `/user/{upn}` or `/me` result so you need to specifically request it using the `$select` query parameter. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get):

> Note: Getting a user returns a default set of properties only (`businessPhones`, `displayName`, `givenName`, `id`, `jobTitle`, `mail`, `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`, `surname`, `userPrincipalName`). Use `$select` to get the other properties and relationships for the user object.

For example, calling `/me` returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 412 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "givenName": "Megan",
    "jobTitle": "Auditor",
    "mail": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "12/1110",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Bowen",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

In order to return `mailNickname` you need to specify that you want this property using `$select`.

Calling `/me?$select=mailNickname` for example will return:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(mailNickname)/$entity",
    "mailNickname": "MeganB"
}
```

You'll notice that `$select` doesn't *add* to the properties that are returned, it specifies the entire set you're requesting. So to include the default set as well as `mailNickname` you would need to add the default properties as well.

For example, calling `/me/?$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id,mailNickname` returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id,mailNickname)/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 412 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "givenName": "Megan",
    "jobTitle": "Auditor",
    "mail": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mailNickname": "MeganB",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "12/1110",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Bowen",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Comment: yes it is working when i pass select query in parameter, v1.0/users?$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id,mailNickname&$filter=startswith(givenName,'{0}') or startswith(displayName,'{0}')  or startswith(surname,'{0}') or startswith(userPrincipalName,'{0}') or startswith(mailNickname,'{0}') or startswith(mail,'{0}')&$top={1}

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. Much appreciated.

Great to know that the mailNickname is the same as alias. I already did some testing with the mailNickName in the select. I get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'mailNickname' on type 'microsoft.graph.person'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5c84fa9e-4989-40aa-b099-0e7bc4dc14cf",
            "date": "2018-06-09T11:56:27"
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is permisson related... cause when i do the same on "me" i DO get my own alias.

I'll contact my site admins to give me some additional privileges...probably this one....

[admin rights needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRaZT.png)

Comment: not the people.readall, but the user.readall permission seems to be needed!